# Process list of strings from R to C

Tags: c, r

This question is related to my other question: [Process list from R to C and access it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50062132/process-list-from-r-to-c-and-access-it).
I want to process a list of strings: `<-list(c("ab", "ac"), c("ab", "zd", "fd"), c("de", "re", "te", "zz"))`.

I struggle with processing strings instead of integers.
I know how to declare a string:

`char string[] = "example";`

But i obviously still have to learn a lot to process the data - my attempt:

```
char stor[] = CHAR(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
// and then store in in a list --> target[i] = stor;
```

The c Code - `d.c`:

```
/* Including some headers to show the results*/
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
SEXP processlist(SEXP lst){
   int i;
   int len = length(lst);

   char **target = malloc(sizeof(char *)*len);
   for (i = 0;i < l; i++) {
     // use char stor[] to store string instead of Array!?
     char stor[] = CHAR(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
     // would i have to modify target[] too?
     target[i] = stor;
   }
   printf("target[0]: %s\n",target[0]);
   printf("target[1]: %s\n",target[1]);
   printf("target[2]: %s\n",target[2]);
   free(target);
   return R_NilValue;
}
```

Equivilant to other post: `d.R` (after d.c has been compiled):

```
dyn.load("d.so")
mylist<-list(c("ab", "ac"), c("ab", "zd", "fd"), c("de", "re", "te", "zz"))
# should be character already? to be sure,...
mylist<-lapply(mylist,as.character)
.Call("processlist", mylist)
```

Comment: just a few references to maybe help: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html, https://github.com/hadley/r-internals, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177777/what-exactly-is-the-sexp-data-type-in-rs-c-api-and-why-is-it-used, http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/

Comment: In general it looks like you still have to allocate memry and copy the value of `stor` to `target[i]`.

Comment: much appreciated for the hints. I will go on!

Comment: Keep in mind this: a string -> `char *`; a vector of strings -> `char **`; a `list` of vectors of strings -> `char ***`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment: a C variable whose content points to the content of the R list must be of type `char ***` since a string is a `char *` and a `vector` of strings is `char **`. Say `target` is that variable. `target[i]` points to the i-th vector of the list; `target[i][j]` is the j-th string of the i-th vector. `target[i][j][k]` is the k-th character of the j-th string of the i-th vector. You need to allocate the outer `target` to the length of the R list; then you need to allocate every `target[i]` to be as long as the corresponding vector they point to. Optionally, you allocate every `target[i][j]` to the length (in number of characters) of the corresponding string if you want to copy the content of the R list. Otherwise, you just assign to `target[i][j]` the corresponding `CHAR(STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(lst,i),j))`.

Hopefully, at this point you should be able to do the task by yourself. However, here is a working code:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
SEXP processlist(SEXP lst){
   int i,j,elLength;
   int len = length(lst);
   SEXP tmp;
   char ***target = malloc(sizeof(char **)*len);
   for (i = 0;i < len; i++) {
     tmp = VECTOR_ELT(lst,i);
     elLength = length(tmp);
     target[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * elLength);
     for (j=0;j<elLength;j++) {
       target[i][j] = CHAR(STRING_ELT(tmp,j));
     }
   }
   printf("target[0][0]: %s\n",target[0][0]);
   printf("target[1][1]: %s\n",target[1][1]);
   printf("target[2][2]: %s\n",target[2][2]);
   for (i=0;i<len;i++)
     free(target[i]);
   free(target);
   return R_NilValue;
}
```

Comment: oh great, thank you! After reading your comment, i arrived at : `CHAR(STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i), j));` and could print the strings. Next i was working on storing the strings again. I will try to finish it myself and can check here how it´s done right ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nicola, you say _if you want to copy the content of the R list..._. Suppose I return the `target` array and later retutrn to R and then come from R to C again, will these strings still exist? So _when_ do I need to copy the strings and _when_ (or: how long) can I use the pointers I get from R?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If you use a `target` outside R with pointers pointing to memory regions handled by R bad things might happen. The R garbage collector may think at a given point that the memory is no longer associated with a R object and free it. So, if you try after that to access it, you end up with a segfault. So, if you intend to use those values outside R, you'd better perform a deep copy of your list.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that. So your example (and OP's) code are fine because the strings are used while in a call from R to C. Any other use would require copying to C storage. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `CHAR(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));` yields a string such as `"hello"`, then `char stor[] = CHAR(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));` declares a character aray `stor` that is initialized to contain that string.

Then `target[i] = stor;` would make the character pointer `target[i]` point to that string. The next round of the loop would do the same for the next entry `target[i]` but you can assume that they all point to the same `stor` (and `stor` goes out of scope after the loop and so would invoke undefined behavior).

Instead, you must safe the string in `stor` by allocating memory for `target[i]` and then copying the string:

```
    target[i]= malloc(strlen(stor)+1);
    strcpy(target[i], stor);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. According to the question `CHAR(VECTOR_ELT(lst, 0))` would yield `{"ab", "ac"} `. So a list of strings rather than a single string. Therefore, the assumption would not hold, i am afraid?